# Fast comparison of strings within data.table

Tags: r, string, data.table

I have a data table with ~20 columns and ~20000 rows.
A small subset looks like this:

```
library(data.table)

DT = data.table(V1 = c('M01000','M01000','M01100','M01000'),
                V2 = c('M01101','M01110','M01000','M01000'),
                V3 = c('M01100','M01110','M00100','M11100'),
                V4 = c('M11100','M01101','M01100','M01101'),
                V5 = c('M01110','M11100','M01110','M01010'))
```

I need to compare strings between all combinations of columns (V1 to V5) and to get a result like this:

```
       V1     V2     V3     V4     V5 diff_V1_V2 diff_V1_V3 diff_V1_V4 diff_V1_V5 diff_V2_V3 diff_V2_V4 diff_V2_V5 diff_V3_V4 diff_V3_V5 diff_V4_V5
1: M01000 M01000 M01100 M11100 M01110          0          1          2          2          1          2          2          1          1          2
2: M01100 M01110 M01110 M01101 M11100          1          1          1          1          0          2          2          2          2          2
3: M01100 M01000 M00100 M01100 M01110          1          1          0          1          2          1          2          1          2          1
4: M01000 M01000 M11100 M01101 M01010          0          2          2          1          2          2          1          2          3          3
```

I developed a code that is too slow for practical implementation:

```
# Get all column combinations
library(string)
CM = combn(c('V1','V2','V3','V4','V5'),2)

# A function that calculates differences between two strings
cmpStrngs = function(x,y){
    sum(str_split(x,pattern = "")[[1]]!=str_split(y,pattern = "")[[1]])
}

# Apply the function
for(i in 1:length(CM[1,])){
r1 = CM[1,i]
r2 = CM[2,i]


for(j in 1:nrow(DT)){
    DT[j,paste0('diff_',r1,'_',r2) := cmpStrngs(get(r1),get(r2))]
}
}

}
```

**What would be the faster solution?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is figure out how I could have less than 20 million rows.

Comment: It sounds like your result would have around 10,000 columns (~100 x ~99) and 20,000,000 rows. As integers, I think that would produce an object of around 800 GB, assuming no overhead in generating it. At that scale (far larger than RAM, I presume), you may need to look at other approaches entirely.

Comment: Mistake. I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `stringdist`?

```
library(stringdist)
DT[
  ,
  c(.SD,
  setNames(
    combn(.SD, 2, function(v) stringdist(v[[1]], v[[2]], method = "hamming"), simplify = FALSE),
    paste0("diff_", combn(names(.SD), 2, function(nms) do.call(paste0, list(nms, collapse = "_"))))
  ))
]
```

which gives

```
       V1     V2     V3     V4     V5 diff_V1_V2 diff_V1_V3 diff_V1_V4
1: M01000 M01101 M01100 M11100 M01110          2          1          2
2: M01000 M01110 M01110 M01101 M11100          2          2          2
3: M01100 M01000 M00100 M01100 M01110          1          1          0
4: M01000 M01000 M11100 M01101 M01010          0          2          2
   diff_V1_V5 diff_V2_V3 diff_V2_V4 diff_V2_V5 diff_V3_V4 diff_V3_V5 diff_V4_V5
1:          2          1          2          2          1          1          2
2:          2          0          2          2          2          2          2
3:          1          2          1          2          1          2          1
4:          1          2          2          1          2          3          3
```